# Redirect/Navigate isn't working

Tags: android, react-native, redirect, react-navigation, react-select

Inside my app, I have a function that supposes to delete the photo once the user clicks "Delete photo" and to redirect the user to HomeScreen. Currently, the function does delete the photo but doesn't redirect the user to the HomeScreen. It just leaves the user in the same photo he deleted. 
Also, I tried to see what response returns, but in my console.log I get an error that variable response is undefined.

My code:

```
onDelete = (photo) => {
        const photoKey = photo.photo.key;
        this.refs.deletePopup.close();

        api.getToken()
        .then(token => api.deleteSafee(photoKey, token))
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
            const resetAction = NavigationActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({routeName: "Home", params: {
                    isRefreshFeed: true
                }})],
            });

            this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)                             
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            showError("Delete Error", error.message);
        });             
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to call the onDelete function?

Comment: @sanjar I didnt write the code , therefore I am not sure, but I think this one: onDelete = (photo) => { const photoKey = photo.photo.key; this.refs.deletePopup.close();

Comment: @sanjar or perhaps this one:  onDelete = () => {
  this.props.onDelete(this.state.photo);
  
 }